# Which of these two should be preferred: "sinification" or "sinicization"?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, neologisms

Which of these two options would be considered most elegant / correct? Personally I think Sinicization (or Sinicisation) has a more natural ring to it, but I have seen Sinification used also.

Also, can anyone give an answer as to when either of these neologisms came into usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to point directly to [Google Ngrams on those words](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=sinification%2Csinicization%2Csinicisation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) to see what the rest of the (English speaking) world actually does:

[image: Google Ngram comparison of sinifi-, sinici-]

I added in the British English spelling, too.

Note that 'sinification' has the longer history, but recently 'sinici[z/s]ation' has become more popular.

To extract a data of word creation from these graphs is a bit iffy; you'd really need to check all the occurrences in the links from that site.

The veribifiers '-ize/-ise' and '-ify' are both productive. I can't seem to tell a pattern in the contexts where one is favored over the other, except that if you're starting with an adjective ending in '-ic', the '-ize/-ise' sounds way better.

Answer (score 4):

Well most of these words seem to use the *ise/ize* form, e.g.:

- *Anglicisation/Anglicization*
- *Germanisation/Germanization*
- *Arabisation/Arabization*

There's *Russification* of course, but I think this is irregular simply because the word *Russicisation* is rather clumsy.

So, I would go with *Sinicisation/Sinicization* by default.

Comment: +1 Also agree that [more socioeconomic/political](http://www.wordbyletter.com/suffixes/words_finishing_with_zation.php) terms have a tendency to use -ization.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at these, both suffixes are very similar. I looked into the meaning of each which are also rather similar. That said, it seems that '*-ization*'leans more toward changing from **one to another** where as '*-cation*' can more often be in an originating process such as fabrication.

Definition of -FICATION from [Your Dictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/fication-suffix)

1. Production; making.

Origin: Latin -ficātiō, -ficātiōn-, from -ficātus, past participle of -ficāre, to make, from -ficus, -fic.

---

Definition of -IZE from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ize)

1. : cause to be or conform to or resemble   : cause to be formed into  (2) : subject to a (specified) action  (3) : impregnate or treat or combine with  b : treat like  c : treat according to the method of
2. : become : become like  b : be productive in or of  : engage in a (specified) activity  c : adopt or spread the manner of activity or the teaching of

Comment: +1 Good answer.  There are quite a lot of other examples where -fication is used for change rather than production though - e.g. beautification (neologism though), beatification, petrification, calcification etc.

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of those alchemy terms!! I had a hard time finding solid definitions for these ;P