# Is there an English verb that comes from the Greek ἀσθενέω (astheneó: to be weak or feeble)?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, greek, obscure-terms

[From Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%80%CF%83%CE%B8%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%AD%CF%89): 3. (with infinitive) to be too weak to do a thing, to be unable

Sample using this definition:
*This friction <astheneo-s> to resist the force.*

An answer in the negative counts.

Comment: Noun:  asthenia  Adj & noun: asthenic Maybe you can coin a verb.

Comment: “This friction *to be weak or feeble* to resist the force” doesn’t make much sense.  Are you looking for an adverb: “This friction *weakly* resists the force”?

Comment: @Jim see the definition from Wiktionary

Comment: I see. So can you say, “This friction asthenically attempts to resist the force.”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After various types of searches, I found that the *French* verb [asthénier](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/asth%C3%A9nier) appears to be ultimately derived from the noun ἀσθένεια, but the online French-English dictionaries I consulted didn't know the verb asthénier.

English has the *nouns* [asthenia and myasthenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakness#Asthenia_vs._myasthenia), which are also based on ἀσθένεια. There is also [legasthenia](http://psychologydictionary.org/legasthenia/) (which looks similar to "Legasthenie", the German word for dyslexia).

I have not found online evidence for the existence of the verb "asthenize".

While you might coin the verb "asthenize", it is not clear whether it would fit into the sentence "This friction  to resist the force." Verbs on `-ize/-ise` usually imply a change, and asthenize would probably mean "to become weaker", which would not make sense in this sentence.

Comment: Is there a pattern of English verb formation from French I could follow to coin this? (-ize seems off.)

Comment: No such verb in the *Oxford English Dictionary* but that's not to say one can't coin it.

Comment: @nebuch As Clare said, you can still coin the verb "asthenize" if it does not exist. You'll probably need to provide a definition when you introduce it in a text, etc. With regard to verb formation, see also [Suffixes for verbification: -ify, -icise, -ificate](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26751/163363).

Comment: It’s not clear to me how you’d work *asthenize* into OP’s desired sentence.

Comment: @Jim You're right. The intended meaning for the missing verb seems to be "is to weak", i.e. something like a stative verb, whereas asthenize sounds like a dynamic verb to me.