# Why do some ---ify verbs have a different noun ending?

Tags: etymology, suffixes, latin, derivational-morphology, endings

The following verbs follow a pattern as to their associated noun:

- rectify / rectification
- amplify / amplification
- exemplify / exemplification
- sanctify / sanctification
- clarify / clarification

*Satisfy* is slightly different – *satisfaction*.

But why are the following two so totally different ?

- crucify / crucifixion
- testify / testimony

I am still searching, but have, as yet, found no explanation.

Comment: I suspect that the answer regarding "testimony" will be unrelated to the answer regarding "crucifixion."  But I like the question regardless.

Comment: **Testification** is a valid word, **testimony** is just a shorter alternative

Comment: I think you should add "beautify / beauty" pair too. :)

Comment: @frederick99 "beautify" goes to "beautification" as per the first set of examples.

Comment: @PhilipC it's the other way; "beautify" comes from "beauty" as is the case with all examples.

Comment: @frederick99 Rectification is the process of rectifying something, amplification is the process of amplifying something and beautification (not beauty) is the process of beautifying something.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### *Crucify* originally had a distinct etymology from the others

*Crucify* comes from Latin *crucifīgō* with the present infinitive *crucifīgere* and the supine ***crucifix***um. It means "to fix to a cross" not "to make into a cross". It ends in *-fy* in English because we got it 
through French; the OED says more specifically that it is from "Old French *crucifier* (12th cent.) = Provençal and Spanish *crucificar,* repr. a late popular Latin type **crucificāre* instead of Latin *cruci fīgĕre* to fasten to the cross, subseq. as one word *crucifīgere.*" Although this verb came to have the same ending as the other verbs you mention, it didn't originally, and the noun *crucifixion* remains faithful to its origins.

### The verb suffix *-ify* comes from Latin verbs that had *-ificat-* forms

The English verb suffix *-ify* (which is moderately productive: you can see an overview of the tendencies for new formations at [What is the difference between the suffixes -ize and -ify?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189530/what-is-the-difference-between-the-suffixes-ize-and-ify) and [Suffixes for verbification: -ify, -icise, -ificate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26751/suffixes-for-verbification-ify-icise-ificate)) comes from Latin verbs ending in *-⁠ificō,* an ending derived from a reduced form of the verb *faciō* "make". Latin verbs ending in *-ificō* belonged to the first conjugation and so had present infinitives ending in *-ificāre* and past supines ending in *-**ificāt**um,* with the thematic vowel A.

#### Some potential *-ification* nouns are "blocked" by other nouns

*Testify* seems to be from Latin *testificor* which basically just conjugates like the passive form of an *-⁠ificō* verb, as it is a first-conjugation deponent verb. It has the participle form ***testificat***um.

The word "testification" exists in English, it's just very uncommon. A well-established preexisting noun related to a verb will usually be preferred over a more complicated noun derived from the verb that would have the same meaning; this is called "blocking", and there are other examples like how **terrification* and **horrification* are very rarely used compared to *terror* and *horror.* Aside from blocking by *testimony,* another thing that might play a role in the low frequency of "testification" is that the meaning of the suffix *-ify* seems to be somewhat more opaque in *testify* than it is in some other words ending in *-ify.*

### The *-(i)faction* nouns are based on the conjugation of Latin *faciō*

*Satisfy* comes from Latin *satisfaciō,* which conjugated like *faciō* in Latin as a third-conjugation verb without vowel reduction. The present infinitive was *satisfacere* and the supine was ***satisfact***um.

There are a number of nouns aside from *satisfaction* that end in *-(i)faction* and are related to verbs ending in *-(i)fy.* See the results for [*ifaction on OneLook Dictionary Search](https://www.onelook.com/?w=*ifaction&ssbp=1&ls=a). One example is *putrefaction* (corresponding to the verb *putrefy*), which seems to be [much more common than *putrefication*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=putrefaction%2C%20putrefication%2C%20putrification%2C%20putrifaction&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cputrefaction%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cputrefication%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cputrification%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cputrifaction%3B%2Cc0). Some other examples are *petrifaction* (corresponding to the verb *petrify*) and *liquefaction* (corresponding to the verb *liquefy*).